# Flattening topography while retaining structures in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, terrain

I have a set of Terrain data in both DSM and DTM form. What I am trying to do is extract the features (buildings, hedges etc...) that have been removed from the DTM, but I don't want the topography. The ideal end result would essentially be an elevation map of all the structures but on a flat plain rather than the rolling hills that are really there.

I have seen that the raster calculator could be used to extract all the parts of one set that are different to the other, but the bit I don't grasp is how I can then flatten the topography while keeping the relative height of the features.

I'm working in QGIS, but I also have access to LSS though I am not very experienced with it.

Comment: DSM - DTM in the raster calculator will give you exactly what you ask for, That is it. Where there are buildings etc. there will be some non-zero values, the rest will be zero because in the rest DTM = DSM.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will run that as soon as my computer is done with the other calculations it is running (which is why I didn't run it yet and find that out myself)

Comment: Just realised that I misunderstood your answer a bit, your solution is even simpler (maybe elegant is a better term) than I realised, thanks :)